# Is the only consistent massless spin-2 QFT really exactly General Relativity in the classical limit or only linearized limit?

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, quantum-gravity

I'm trying to understand to what extent it is a "miracle" that a massless spin-2 field "postdicts" general relativity. I think there is some early theorem of Weinberg that shows under various assumptions and consistency requirements that spin-2 can't like be a yang-mills type theory, it has to couple in a gravity-like way, but I'm trying to understand exactly what this means. Are these arguments just for perturbations around flat spacetime, i.e. we don't know at all if they would describe observational classical general relativity around e.g. stars? To what extent do we really know that a massless spin-2 particle uniquely postdicts general relativity. For example, if general relativity hadn't yet been discovered, would the study of QFT lead people to come up with the exact Einstein equation for macroscopic matter as an inevitable consequence of any massless spin-2 QFT?

Comment: Concerning the title question, what are you calling the "linearized limit"? Is it only the quadratic Fierz-Pauli part of the action (in the perturbation), or the full expansion of the EH action in terms of the perturbation? For the latter, and according to Deser https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0411023 after eq(1), it is a matter of imposing recursively some properties to the Fierz-Pauli equation of motion when there are interactions.

Comment: I mean does massless spin 2 imply: a) weak field limit, b) classical strong field limit (but not UV), whereas I assume c) high energy / small distance would require a fuller quantum theory of gravity.